# Chose record with highest qty from domain search

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

This search on domain retuns me 2 records. I want to filter record with higher quantity. so can i do something like this in domain `('qty','<=',line.quantity),('qty','>',line.quantity)`?
Just need that suplier_inf got me 1 record with highest qty.

```py
  for line in invocie.invoice_line_ids:
                domain = [('product_tmpl_id', '=', line.product_id.product_tmpl_id.id),
                          ('name', '=', line.partner_id.id)]
                suplier_inf = self.env['product.supplierinfo'].search(domain)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is to sort the result already on `search()`:

```py
suplier_inf = self.env['product.supplierinfo'].search(domain, order="qty desc")
```

Parameter `order` will be used as `ORDER BY <parameter content>` in the query Odoo is creating for the search. As default Odoo uses the models `_order` attribute or as fallback `id` (`ORDER BY id`). That's why the parameter isn't required but useful!

Answer (score 0):

We can sort record by qty and if we use `reverse=True` first record always well be with highest quantity.

```py
sup_inf = suplier_inf.sorted(key=lambda rec: rec.qty, reverse=True)
```

`sup_inf[0]` always be record with highest quantity

Comment: Always consider that there is no supplierinfo, hence index 0 could just not exist.

Comment: Yes, thank you, but in my case, there always will be records. :)

Comment: Don't bet on it ;-) a little check won't hurt ;-)